# Script - Cutting various lines and sort them

Tags: grep, sort, cpu, cut

i want to sort the process of one user by the percentage of cpu used. I tried this

```
ps aux|tr -s " "|cut -f3 -d " "| sort -| grep "user" > file name
```

does this work?

Answer (score 3):

`ps` allows you to specify the columns in the output, as well the sort order. Depending upon your requirements, an additional command may not even be needed for post-processing.

Here's a command that provides a list of the specified user's processes, sorted by their percentage of CPU utilization. (The `head` command is merely there to restrict the output).

```
[root@testvm ~]# ps -o pid,uname,pcpu,command -u root --sort=-pcpu | head
  PID USER     %CPU COMMAND
    1 root      0.5 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 21
  664 root      0.4 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
 1226 root      0.2 sshd: root@pts/0
 1261 root      0.2 [kworker/0:0]
    9 root      0.1 [rcu_sched]
   20 root      0.1 [kworker/0:1]
  293 root      0.1 [kworker/0:1H]
  875 root      0.1 -bash
 1008 root      0.1 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/tuned -l -P
```

The `-o` option specifies the output format here, which are the following columns: Process ID, Username, Percentage of CPU Usage, & Command.

The `-u` option limits `ps` to a specific user's processes, which in this case is root.

The `--sort` option defines the sorting order, which is percentage of CPU usage. The prefixed `-` symbol defines the sort in descending order.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider limiting the initial retrieval to the specific user and sorting, then possibly cutting.

`ps hux -u USER | sort -k3 -n`

By taking this approach, the processes are already limited to the specific user. The sort is then performed against the whole retrieved process. It can then be piped through the `tr` and `cut` if desired for specific fields.

Parameters:
  `h` : suppress the headers
  `u` : user oriented format
  `x` : BSD remove the tty requirement

`-u` USER : the specific user for whom processes should be selected. Note that this may be a list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
ps aux | grep user | sort -rk3 > file_name
```

Read about `sort -rk3` with `man sort`

A couple things about yours:

- spaces are important, bash doesn't know that `file name` is one file, it's going to redirect output to a file called `file` and then wonder what to do with `name`.  If you must put spaces in filenames, you'll have to quote them: `... > "file name"`.
- Many linux apps are kind of smart about picking columns out without counting/collapsing spaces.  If I wanted just the percentages I'd do this:

  `ps aux | grep user | sort -rk3 | awk '{print $3}'`

  `cut` is probably smart like that too, I'm just less familiar with it.
- You might also consider `top -bn1 | grep user` which does something similar